# pgfplots axis abbreviation

Tags: pgfplots

Suppose I have a pgfplot with the following axis text:

```
|-----|-----|-----|------|
0    500  1000  1500  2000
```

Is there a way to change axis text to:

```
|-----|-----|-----|------|
0    0.5K  1K   1.5K    2K
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

1. You transform your data on the fly using

   ```
   x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/1000}}
   ```

   and format the labels using

   ```
   xticklabel = \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,K
   ```
2. You only transform the label value using

   ```
   xticklabel = {
       \pgfmathparse{\tick/1000}
       \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,K
   }
   ```

[image]

The result in this case is identical, but the behaviour of the two solutions is slightly different. Using the first method, you would have to specify axis limits using transformed units (e.g. `xmax=1.5` instead of `xmax=1500`). However, that solution has the advantage that it will also work with factors that aren't as "nice" as `1000`. Consider the case where you want to convert from bytes to kibibytes, which is a factor of 1024. If you used the second solution, the tick marks would be placed at `0.488 Ki`, `0.977 Ki`, etc., while the first solution would place the labels at `0.5 Ki`, `1 Ki`, etc.

First solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain = 0:2000,
    x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/1000}},
    xticklabel = \pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,K
]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Second solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain = 0:2000,
    xticklabel = {
        \pgfmathparse{\tick/1000}
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,K
    }
]
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The kilo prefix should be written as 'k', in lowercase. ;)

Comment: @OSjerick: I agree, the kilo prefix should be lower case, but the "k" here is not the SI prefix (since that's never allowed to stand without a unit symbol), but rather the [informal use of "K" for "thousand of something"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#Similar_symbols_in_abbreviations) (and also mimics the OP's usage).

Answer (score 5):

Instead doing Jake's solution, you can use SI prefixes, including a prefix inside the x axis unit.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\begin{document}
    %Without prefix
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[change x base,
            x unit=m,
            y unit=N,
            xlabel=Distance,ylabel=Force]
            \addplot coordinates {
            (1000,1)
            (2000,1.1)
            (3000,1.2)
            (4000,1.3)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    %With prefix
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[change x base,
            x SI prefix=kilo,x unit=m,
            y SI prefix=milli,y unit=N,
            xlabel=Distance,ylabel=Force]
            \addplot coordinates {
            (1000,1)
            (2000,1.1)
            (3000,1.2)
            (4000,1.3)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

From section 5.14, page 527 inside [pgfplots](http://ctan.uniminuto.edu/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) manual.

Comment: Ah yes, of course!

Comment: My data is unit-less, so I'll be using Jakes solution, but thanks for providing this clever solution. Might come in handy at some time. :)

Comment: @TomKeegasi You're welcome. Don't worry, the solution maybe is useful for someone else.